# Installed Android Studio 0.8.1 but can't get into IDE since no Android SDK

Tags: java, android

I installed (after unzipping) `android-studio-ide-135.1224218-windows`, hoping to be up and running a "hello world" program by now, but the IDE won't even start because "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or missing templates." It tells me "You can configure your SDK via Configure | Project Defaults | Project Structure | SDKs" but when I do so, I see NOTHING in the text box for Android SDK location.

I searched for "android sdk" on my computer, and found `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\plugins\android\lib\sdk-common.jar`, but when I put that or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\plugins\android\lib` into the text box, I get NO ERROR, but then I get the same message, and when I come back to the text box, IT DOESN'T HAVE WHAT I PUT INTO IT.

If I browse for the text box location, no matter what I put in, it says "Please choose a valid SDK directory".

That's the only "android sdk" on my computer.

I JUST installed Android Studio to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio` with no errors.

I have `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60` as JDK location. It won't let me change it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25`.

I've Googled to see if I can download an android sdk from somewhere but found nothing.

WHAT DO I DO? I can't get into the  IDE to try stuff.

Comment: `android.bat` is located in `$ANDROID_HOME/tools` where `$ANDROID_HOME` is the directory where the SDK is installed. I suggest that you add this directory to your PATH.

Comment: *IS* SDK-COMMON.JAR the sdk?? Because that's all I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't make use of the Answers above, so I uninstalled and then brute-force deleted EVERY trace of Android EVERYTHING.

Then I downloaded and installed `installer_r23-windows.exe`, putting the SDK manager out there BEFORE installing the Android Studio IDE. I allowed the default path: `C:\Users\Dov\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`.

Then I downloaded and installed `android-studio-bundle-135.1245622-windows.exe`--NOTE: **BUNDLE**, NOT IDE. I used the default folder: `C:\Users\Dov\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio`.

And I STILL got the SAME ERROR. But at least THIS time I could go into SDK Manager, as the error message said to do.

What I found was that the CORRECT path to the JDK, which was the same path shown in the SDK Manager dialog for installing packages. So why the error?

LOOOOOOONG story short... as I tried to browse for the path, I noticed that the `AppData` folder WAS NOT SHOWING.

SOLUTION: TYPE THE PATH BY HAND. It worked.

I CHANGED NOTHING, except my approach.

As it happens, "The [AppData] folder is hidden by default in File Explorer, and has three hidden sub-folders: Local, LocalLow, and Roaming." [See here.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/what-appdata-folder)

I assume that was Android Studio's problem, but why typing it by hand changed all that is anybody's guess.

I guess it's not a great idea to have AppData part of the DEFAULT install path.

(BTW, I did NOT have to mess with ANY environment variables.)

=== EDIT ===

I reinstalled Studio and SDK Manager and the above did not work. What I did BOTH times was to TRY to drag the `SDK Manager.EXE` file into the browse dialog from an Explorer window; it didn't work either time, but I tried today and THEN found success.... So I guess this seems to be a necessary step.... I also added `\` after `sdk` in the text box for the SDK path.... And I clicked `Apply` before `OK`.... I *hate* when stuff works seemingly randomly.... Just trying to save others the frustration. Maybe Google needs to address this.

Answer (score 1):

`sdk-common.jar` is not the 'sdk' that Android Studio is looking for. You must download the sdk from SDK Manager and put it in the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk`. 
This is what the sdk should contain:

`sdk\build-tools
sdk\extras
sdk\platforms
sdk\platform-tools
...`

Comment: AFAIK, the SDK download that we are used to is now included in with Android Studio and doesn't need to be downloaded separately.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice You are right. Downloading the sdk directly in Android Studio is fine.

Comment: But only if you can get into Android Studio, which you CAN'T in the presence of this common (as Google and SO clearly show) error. (At least *I* couldn't get in.)

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this problem. After downloading Android Studio from the developer site:

android-studio-ide-135.1538390-windows.zip

But kept getting the error: "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or missing templates."

Wasted several hours, but eventually went to the "Installing the Stand-alone SDK Tools" page:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools

And downloaded and installed installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe.

Then I added its location to Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure

I can now create projects.